# asp.net - c# - How can I call a method inside code-behind using jQuery?

Tags: c#, asp.net, jquery, telerik, web-applications

My pages base on master and content pages and in content pages I have Multiviews; inside Multiviews I have RadComboBoxes.

Two of my RadComboBoxes are parent and child, like country and city dropdowns. Therefore in code-behind I put some code in the OnSelectedIndexChange event of parent RadComboBox for filling its child; I use a hidden field for country id and sql datasources (stored procedures). Meantime parent and child combo boxes are in an update panel.

For doing this job i set the autopostback property of parent combobox to true,
but I do not want that autopostback=true because of some focus problems that I coded with jQuery.

So I want to convert the OnSelectedIndexChange event in code-behind to a method and call it in jQuery (in change event or something like that of parent combobox). How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By `$.ajax` and by declaring your method a [WebMethod](http://www.dexign.net/post/2008/07/16/jQuery-To-Call-ASPNET-Page-Methods-and-Web-Services.aspx)